# Running a Java program inside a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, chess

I am making an GUI of a chess game. And i thought that i could run the chess game in a JPanel, and have some meny options in another. This way i could fit everything in one window. Is it possible to run a JPanel which runs another java class inside?

Edit:
I mean running an entire java program inside of that JPanel, so the output of the chess program goes in to that JPanel inside my GUI program. Im not talking about a simple frame within a frame.

I am using lwjgl tools, which is a game developing tool. It runs it's own window which i am trying to run inside a JPanel. I am familiar with border layouts etc, but i don't know if it is possible to run a external program within a JPanel. the chess game not extend JPanel, it extends "BasicGame" which is a part of "Lightweight Java Game Library" or "ljgl". Everything is in java.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse it's possible. You can use a JPanel as "main panel" and then store other JPanels inside your main panel, and that way have a framelike apperance.

If you use BorderLayout on your mainPanel, you can store one panel in the center (representing the chess board) and one panel on the west side. The panel on the westside can have a different layout, GridLayout for example which allows you to create buttons representing different actions the player can make

Comment: I mean running an entire java program inside of that JPanel, so the output of the chess program goes in to that JPanel inside my GUI program.

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you mean. But if you have a "ChessBoard" class which extends JPanel, you can use that class to draw the chessboard (either by using a background image or using GridLayout) and update the players moves on that panel. And then add that panel to your program. Your program can contain another panel which represent the players options

Comment: @Jimmy I think he means writing his chess game in Java but writing the GUI in another language.... I could be wrong though :D .

Comment: I am using lwjgl tools, which is a game developing tool. It runs it's own window which i am trying to run inside a JPanel. I am familiar with the layouts, but i don't know if it is possible to run a external program within a JPanel.

Everything is in java btw. 

It does not extend JPanel, it extends "BasicGame" which is a part of  "Lightweight Java Game Library" or "ljgl".

Comment: Ah ok, Then me and probably everyone else was a bit confused by your question :) If the lwjgl generates javacode, it will be pretty simple to integrate your "engine" with your "view" using the source code. Don't think you can integrate them using two different programs (say you start program one, and then program two gets started inside program one as happends with an applet). What you need is one or few classes representing the GUI, and then connect the GUI with the classes generated with lwjgl

Comment: Thats what i am trying to figure out! :) maybe i lack some understanding using the lwjgl tools. But i am trying to have a main GUI class, if i throw in the chess code inside of the GUI, it would be impossible to maintain or edit without getting frustrated.

Comment: Im afraid I can't help you more with the info you provided. I have no working experience with lwjgl, or even know what it is :) Altho you can post a new question, that contains what you are trying to achive and sample code of what you've tried so far, so that we can take a look at it. If it's only a matter of integrating the GUI with the VIEW it should not be complicated

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can add several JPanels to a single JFrame. You can even add a JPanel to a different JPanel. Just call frame.add for both panels.